# limit of a sequence $(1+1/\sqrt 2+\dots+1/\sqrt n)/\sqrt n$ - need a review of my solution

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

$$\eqalign{
  & {a_n} = {1 \over {\sqrt n }}(1 + {1 \over {\sqrt 2 }} + ... + {1 \over {\sqrt n }})  \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\sqrt n }} + {1 \over {\sqrt n \sqrt 2 }} + ...{1 \over n} \cr} $$

Now, it's easy to see the sequence is bounded by $({1 \over {\sqrt n }},{1 \over n})$
In addition, you can see the sequence is monotonically decreasing.

so, I can say the limit is the infimum of the series which is ${1 \over n}$
and the limit of ${1 \over n}$ is 0.

in conclusion,
$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_n} = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
a_n\geq\frac1{\sqrt n}\,\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}+\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)=\frac1{\sqrt n}\, \frac n{\sqrt n}=1.
$$
Actually,
$$
a_n\geq\frac1{\sqrt n}\,\int_1^{n}\,\frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}=2-\frac{2}{\sqrt n}.
$$
And you can get an estimate the other way by
$$
a_n\leq\frac1{\sqrt n}\,\int_1^{n+1}\,\frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}=\frac{2\sqrt{n+1}-2}{\sqrt n}
$$
So $\lim_na_n=2$.