# limit of a sequence $(1+1/\sqrt 2+\dots+1/\sqrt n)/\sqrt n$: Cesaro maybe?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

What is the limit of:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {1 \over {\sqrt n }}(1 + {1 \over {\sqrt 2 }} + ...{1 \over {\sqrt n }})$$

It looks like I need to use Cesaro theorem but I'm not sure how exactly..

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556819/limit-of-a-sequence-need-a-review-of-my-solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**
One approach would be [Cezaro Stoltz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

Where $b_n = \sqrt n$ , $a_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} $

Another way would be estimate the numerator by integrals 
namely
$$ \int _{2}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \rm{d}  \leq (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}) \leq \int _{1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \rm{d}x$$

Comment: OK, thanks. I mistakenly thought An = 1/sqrt(n)

Comment: Wait a sec. Wolfram alpha is telling me ${1 \over {n + 1 - \sqrt n *\sqrt {n + 1} }}$ limit is 2 but I can't see why..

Comment: @captaindragon Multiply by $((n+1)+ \sqrt n \sqrt{n+1})$ the numerator and denumerator, to get rid of the square roots down there. Can you see it now?

Comment: Like the bright sky! cheers

Comment: I don't quite get it @captaindragon: you say to Chris that you can't use integrals as you haven't yet studied that, yet the above is fine...?

Answer (score 10):

I would probably use Riemann sums, i.e. $\text{lim} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot (1+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) = \text{lim} \frac{1}{n}\cdot (\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}+... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{n}}}) = \int_{0}^{1} x^{\frac{-1}{2}} dx = 2\sqrt{1} = 2$.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not allowed to use it, for haven't learned it yet

Comment: @captaindragon, using the Cezaro-Stoltz method given by Clark you should get as your final step: $lim \frac{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$. I hope this helps.

Comment: I assumed that you would be allowed to use Riemann sums as that was the natural progression of my first-year analysis course. However, books like Rudin approach it differently.

Comment: Anyhow, your help is very appreciated to me.

Comment: I haven't taken any Analysis courses, but I do recall Riemann sums being covered in Freshman Calculus.